# Постраничный вывод из mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi народ! Какая вот проблемка. Есть скрипт вывода инфы постранично из базы. В php особо не силен. Скрипт не вывод данные!!! Ошибок не выдает. 
Собственно скрипт:

```
<?php

function link_bar($page, $pages_count)
{
for ($j = 1; $j <= $pages_count; $j++)
{
// Вывод ссылки
if ($j == $page) {
echo ' <a style="color: #808000;" ><b>'.$j.'</b></a> ';
} else {
echo ' <a style="color: #808000;" href='.$_SERVER['php_self'].'?page='.$j.'>'.$j.'</a> ';
}
// Выводим разделитель после ссылки, кроме последней
// например, вставить "|" между ссылками
if ($j != $pages_count) echo ' | ';
}
return true;
} // Конец функции

// Подключение к базе данных
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die('error! Нет соединения с сервером mysql!');
mysql_select_db('info') or die('error! Нет соединения с базой данных!');

// Подготовка к постраничному выводу
$perpage = 10; // Количество отображаемых данных из БД

if (empty($_GET['page']) || ($_GET['page'] <= 0)) {
    $page = 1;
} 
    else {
$page = (int) $_GET['page']; // Считывание текущей страницы
}

// Общее количество информации
$count = mysql_numrows(mysql_query('select * from dta')) or die('error! Записей не найдено!');
$pages_count = ceil($count / $perpage); // Количество страниц

// Если номер страницы оказался больше количества страниц
if ($page > $pages_count) $page = $pages_count;
$start_pos = ($page - 1) * $perpage; // Начальная позиция, для запроса к БД

// Вызов функции, для вывода ссылок на экран
link_bar($page, $pages_count);

// Вывод информации из базы данных
echo '<p><b>Page Posting!</b></p>';
$result = mysql_query('select * from dta limit '.$start_pos.', '.$perpage) or die('error!');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<p>'.$row['some_field'].'</p>';
}

?>
```

Хотя в БД много записей. Разделил на кол-во страниц правильно - значит соединился и прочитал общие количество записей. В чем же проблема?
Скрин: [link text](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Vydelenie_185.1420610905.png)

Comment: GET! Спсибо!. Люди простите - надо спать по ночам, а не пялиться в монитор!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что такое `$row['some_field']`? У вас в БД есть колонка `some_field`?